# Caddy Server, http.fastcgi 502 Error

Tags: php, fastcgi, caddy

My Caddy File

```
http://bot.vibs.tech {
root /home/caddy/www/botsite
tls off
errors {
    404 /home/caddy/www/botsite/404.html
}
fastcgi / 127.0.0.1:9001 php {
ext     .php
split   .php
index   index.php
}
```

}

The Webpage http://bot.vibs.tech/test.php
Home Page http://bot.vibs.tech

My PHP Script

```
<?php

if($_POST["submit"]) {
    $test=$_POST["botsname"];
    $redis->set(';message';, $test;);
    $value = $redis->get('message');
    <p>$value</p>
}
if (empty($url)) {
    echo "<h2><div style=\"color: Black;\">THANK YOU, YOUR BOT IS BEING MADE!</div></h2>";
    echo "<h2><div style=\color: Black;\"><a href=http://bot.vibs.tech/>HOME</a></div></h2>";
}
```

Tried lots of different things, not sure what else i could try to do.

Also im trying to implement Redis to this so i can have a database from a form im currently working on.

Additional Info

tried /etc/init.d/php7.0-fpm status

```
● php7.0-fpm.service - The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php7.0-fpm.service; enabled; vendor 

preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-08-26 11:27:49 EDT; 4min 55s ago
  Process: 17295 ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/php/php7.0-fpm-checkconf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 17304 (php-fpm7.0)
   Status: "Processes active: 0, idle: 2, Requests: 0, slow: 0, Traffic: 0req/sec"
   CGroup: /system.slice/php7.0-fpm.service
           ├─17304 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
           ├─17305 php-fpm: pool www
           └─17306 php-fpm: pool www

Aug 26 11:27:49 Vibs systemd[1]: Starting The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager...
Aug 26 11:27:49 Vibs systemd[1]: Started The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Says its started.

Also Did,  ps aux | grep php-fpm

```
root     17304  0.0  0.8 211748 17128 ?        Ss   11:27   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
www-data 17305  0.0  0.1 211748  3224 ?        S    11:27   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data 17306  0.0  0.1 211748  3224 ?        S    11:27   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
caddy    18003  0.0  0.0  11228   884 pts/0    S+   15:33   0:00 grep --color=auto php-fpm
```

Comment: Did you verify your fastcgi process is running on that address? (Also, get rid of the ext, split, and index properties in your Caddyfile - they're redundant with the 'php' preset). Then try the suggestions on [this wiki page](https://github.com/mholt/caddy/wiki/Troubleshooting-PHP-FPM-and-FastCGI).

Comment: Updated My post.